# RC4 stream cipher in ARM Assembly

Tags: cryptography, assembly, arm

Below is a complete implementation of [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) in ARM assembly.  Unit tests pass, including comparison to C implementation and to published test vectors.

I'm appreciative of all feedback, comments (things you like and things you don't), and suggestions, but particularly value your thoughts on:

- Performance.  Could the code be faster?
- Clarity.  How it could it be clearer? Use of idioms and patterns?
- Comments.  In C, you can name variables appropriately to make code self-documenting, whereas in ASM you generally stick with the register names.  So I comment ASM in detail, but endeavor to do so in a way which doesn't interfere with the code, become cumbersome, or potentially desync.  I enumerate what I do with each reg, and try to use comments to keep the asm connected to the higher level C it might implement.  How well does this work?

I use GNU gas assembler, which allows comments to begin with `#` or, in ARM, `@`.  My editor doesn't recognize the latter, so I add `;` to make the syntax highlighting work.  Pasting the code into Stackoverflow seems to change the alignment, so please forgive the extra spacing on some lines.

*Usage:* For one-shot invocation, `rc4()` is self contained.  When iterating through streams, use `ksa()` once and then `prga()` on each successive buffer.

```
# rc4

.arm
.text

# void rc4_a(const char* key, uint32_t key_len, uint8_t* buf, uint32_t buf_len);
.global rc4_a
rc4_a:
    .equ _pi, 0x00
    .equ _pj, 0x04
    .equ _S,  0x08
    push {r4-r7, lr}
    sub sp, sp, #(2 * 4 + 0x100)
    mov r4, #0
    str r4, [sp, #_pi]
    str r4, [sp, #_pj]

    mov r4, r0
    mov r5, r1
    mov r6, r2
    mov r7, r3
    add r2, sp, #_S 
    bl ksa_a
    mov r0, r6
    mov r1, r7
    add r2, sp, #_S
    add r3, sp, #_pi
    add r4, sp, #_pj
    push {r4} 
    bl prga_a
    add sp, sp, #(3 * 4 + 0x100)
    pop {r4-r7, lr}
    bx lr

# void prga_a(uint8_t* buf, uint32_t buf_len, uint8_t S[256], uint8_t* i, uint8_t* j);
.global prga_a
prga_a:
# i := 0
# j := 0
# while GeneratingOutput:
#   i := (i + 1) mod 256
#   j := (j + S[i]) mod 256
#   swap values of S[i] and S[j]
#   K := S[(S[i] + S[j]) mod 256]
#   output K

        # r0: unsigned char* buf
        # r1: Initially: buf_len
        # r1: During execution: buf + buf_len
        # r2: char S[256]
        # r3: Initially: &i_
        # r3: During execution: i
        # sp: Initially: &j_
        # r4: j
        # r5: S[i]
        # r6: S[j]
        # r7: S[S[i]+S[j]]
        # r8: *(buf++)
        .equ _pi, ((0)*4)               @; r3=&i, since r3 is lowest reg, it will push to sp
        .equ _pj, ((8-3+1)*4)   @; &j is at sp before pushing r3-r8 (ie 6 words)

        cmp r1, #0
        bxeq lr                 @; if (buf_len == 0) return
        add r1, r1, r0  @; r1 = buf + buf_len
        push {r3-r8}
        ldr r3, [sp, #_pi]
        ldrb r3, [r3]   @; r3 = i
        ldr r4, [sp, #_pj]
        ldrb r4, [r4]   @; r4 = j

.L3:                    @; PERFORMANCE: Consider unrolling this loop, 
                        @;              to allow ldr/str of more than 1 byte
                        @;              of buf at a time.
        add r3, r3, #1          @; i++
        and r3, r3, #0xff   @; i %= 256
        ldrb r5, [r2, r3]   @; r5 = S[i]
        add r4, r4, r5      @; j += S[i]
        and r4, r4, #0xff   @; j %= 256

    ldrb r6, [r2, r4]   @; swap(&S[i], &S[j])
    strb r5, [r2, r4]
    strb r6, [r2, r3]

    add r7, r5, r6         @; r7 = (S[i] + S[j])
    and r7, #0xff      @;      % 256
    ldrb r7, [r2, r7]  @; r7 = S[r7]
        ldrb r8, [r0], #1  @; r8 = *(buf++)
        eor r8, r8, r7     @; r8 ^= S[(S[i] + S[j]) % 256]
        strb r8, [r0, #-1] @; *(buf-1) ^= S[(S[i] + S[j]) % 256]
        cmp r0, r1                
        blt .L3

        ldr r6, [sp, #_pi]
        ldr r7, [sp, #_pj]
        strb r3, [r6]      @; *i_ = i
        strb r4, [r7]      @; *j_ = j
        pop {r3-r8}
        bx lr

# void ksa_a(const char* key, uint32_t key_len, uint8_t S[256]);
.global ksa_a
ksa_a:
# for i from 0 to 255
#    S[i] := i
# j := 0
# for i from 0 to 255
#    j := (j + S[i] + key[i mod keylength]) mod 256
#    swap values of S[i] and S[j]

    # r0: const char* key
    # r1: unsigned int key_len
    # r2: unsigned char[256] S
    # r3: int i

    push {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8}
    mov r3, #0         @; i = 0
.L0:
    strb r3, [r2, r3]  @; S[i] = i
    add r3, r3, #1     @; i++
    cmp r3, #0x100     @; while (i < 256)
    blt .L0

    cmp r1, #0         @; if (key_len == 0) return
    beq .L2

    # r4: unsigned char j
    # r5: unsigned int k // Points to byte of key
    # r6: S[i]
    # r7: S[j]
    # r8: key[k]
    mov r3, #0                 @; i = 0
    mov r4, #0                 @; j = 0
    mov r5, #0         @; k = 0
.L1:
    # j += (S[i] + key[k % key_len])
    ldrb r6, [r2, r3]  @; r6 = S[i]
    ldrb r8, [r0, r5]  @; r8 = key[k]
    add r4, r4, r6     @; j += S[i]
    add r4, r4, r8     @; j += key[k]
    and r4, r4, #0xff  @; j %= 256
    # swap(&S[i], &S[j])
    ldrb r7, [r2, r4]
    strb r6, [r2, r4]
    strb r7, [r2, r3]
    add r3, r3, #1     @; i++
    add r5, r5, #1         @; k++
    cmp r5, r1         @; k %= key_len
    moveq r5, #0
    cmp r3, #0x100     @; while (i < 256)
    blt .L1

.L2:
    pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8}            
    bx lr
```

Comment: It may help you get better reviews if you include the unit tests here.  And reviewers might improve the testing, too!

Comment: You might want to add a like to a description of what RC4 is for those of us who don't know.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4